# get values from fgets using strtok

Tags: c, fgets, strtok

I receive some data every 10 seconds from an external machine (always 4 lines) like:

```
Yesterday match:
Player_1:(P=31,Reb=12)
Yesterday match:
Player_2:(P=12,Reb=2)
```

I have the following code which reads the data (I have also open and configure serial ports functions):

```
int learn_data(int fd)
{
  int n,i;
  char buff[200];
  memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
  char* ptr;
  FILE *fp=fdopen(fd,"r");
 while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp) != NULL)
 { 
    printf("%s", buff);
 }
}
```

With this code fgets reads line by line the buffer. Now my question is, how can I get The values of points and rebounds (31,12), (12,2) etc with the usage of strtok? How can I escape  the first and third line?

Comment: `if (strchr(buff, '(') != NULL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a well-formatted input, you're okay with `sscanf()`. Try the following:

```
int P, Reb;
sscanf(buff, "%*7s%*d%*4s%d%*5s%d", &P, &Reb);
```

To deal only with `Player*`, you can do `memcmp()` first. Like,

```
if(memcmp(buff, "Player_", 7) == 0) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the player names are formatted — do the names ever include spaces, in particular.   I'd probably use:

```
while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp))
{
    int points, rebounds;
    if (sscanf(buff, "%100[^(](P=%d,Reb=%d)", &points, &rebounds) == 2)
        ...process a valid entry...
}
```

This will effectively skip the odd lines (the ones with the match information) and will only process those with a name and the points and rebounds figures.